# Pulling random data from Cassandra DB

Tags: nosql, cassandra

How can you pull some # of random keys from a Cassandra supercolumn?

Answer (score 2):

You mean, random columns?

I guess you'd need to read them all to the client and use random.choice or something, it won't do that for you server-side.